# Setting each line in a file to a GlyphLayout in java libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to have 5 separate `GlyphLayout` objects that contain the 5 lines in a file. I can't seem to get this to work properly, here is how I populate an `ArrayList` of strings

```
for(String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\debugger.txt"))) {
    fileElements.add(line);
}
```

`fileElements` is the `ArrayList` of Strings. There is another `ArrayList` of `GlyphLayout` objects called `glyphs` Here is how I am trying to render it

```
public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
    elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    if (elapsedTime > .1f) {
        if (stringCounter < fileElements.get(count).length()) {
            tmpString += fileElements.get(count).substring(stringCounter, stringCounter + 1);
            glyphs.get(count).setText(font, tmpString);
            elapsedTime = 0;
            stringCounter++;
        } else if (count < fileElements.size() - 1) {
            count++;
            stringCounter = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < glyphs.size(); i++)
        font.draw(batch, glyphs.get(i), position.x, position.y + (10 * i));
}
```

The elapsedTime is just so it prints one letter at a time so it looks smooth however this is what happens:

[image: File contents]

Any help is extremely appreciated, I need to have Question, answer 1, answer 2, etc all on seperate lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this by using a single BitmapFontCache. You can keep the entire String intact and let the font cache handle the layout of multiple lines. (If you need control over the vertical spacing you can use `font.getData().lineHeight = whatever;`.) So you only need to track one BitmapFontCache instead of multiple GlyphLayouts and Strings.

```
cache = new BitmapFontCache(font);
```

To set up your string to draw, do this. You need to count the number of glyphs to know how many to draw (the number of glyphs doesn't match the length of the String because of white space):

```
GlyphLayout glyphLayout = cache.setText(yourString, position.x, position.y);
glyphsToDraw = 0;
for (GlyphLayout.GlyphRun run : glyphLayout.runs) glyphsToDraw += run.glyphs.size;
```

And then rendering is pretty simple:

```
public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
    elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    cache.draw(batch, 0, Math.min(glyphsToDraw, (int)(elapsedTime * CHARS_PER_SECOND)));
}
```